# How to return the hash key if the value is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Given a hash

```
  PLATFORMS = {
      :mac => /(mac)|(macintosh)/i,
      :win => /(win)|(windows)/i,
      :ipad => /(ipad)/i,
      :iphone => /(iphone)/i,
      :ipod => /(ipod)|(ipod touch)/i
  }
```

I am interested in returning the hash key, where the value (in this case is a regex expression) returns true.

So if I am given a string of `"windows"`, I should be returned the key `:win`.

My attempt so far is:

```
current_platform = BrowserExperience::ExperienceKeeper::PLATFORMS.detect do |platform, regex|        
   regex.match(user_agent_obj.platform)
end[0]
```

It returns `[:win,/(win)|(windows)/i]`

However, that just returns an array, where index 0 returns the key value I desire. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: As a sidenote, you could simplify your regex expressions.  It's impossible to match 'macintosh' without matching 'mac' and likewise for 'windows' and 'ipod touch'

Comment: It's possible to not match substrings by using word-boundary markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given hash I would write the following.

```
def attempt_match(str)
  PLATFORMS.keys.find { |k| str.match? PLATFORMS[k] }
end

attempt_match 'windows' #=> :win
attempt_match 'DOS' #=> nil
```

A DRYer approach would be to use a simpler hash and construct the regular expressions (which are all quite similar) dynamically. This could be implemented as follows<sup>1</sup>.

```
def attempt_match(h, s)
  sdn = s.downcase
  h.find { |k, _| sdn.match?(/\b#{k}\b/) }&.last
end

h = {"mac"=>:mac, "windows"=>:win, "ipad"=>:ipad, "iphone"=>:iphone, "ipod"=>:ipod}

attempt_match(h, 'windows') #=> :win
attempt_match(h, 'DOD')     #=> :nil
```

`&` in `&.last` is Ruby's [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), introduced in v2.3.

It would be a simple matter to modify the hash (add `"linux"=>:linux`, for example) without having to worry about getting the regex right.

<sup>1 Observe that if "ipod touch" were matched, so would "ipod". Therefore, the former is redundant.</sup>

Comment: I will try this out on Monday. This seems the most promising to me. At least reasonably simple.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a `case` statement? It's a more common way to do this:

```
strings = [
  'this is a Windows box',
  'Welcome to Macintosh',
  'My music is on an iPod',
  'My photos are on an iPod Touch',
  'I read books on an iPad'
]

strings.each do |str|
  os = case str
       when /\b(?:mac|macintosh)\b/i
         :mac 
       when /\b(?:win|windows)\b/i
         :win 
       when /\b(?:ipad)\b/i
         :ipad 
       when /\b(?:iphone)\b/i
         :iphone 
       when /\b(?:ipod|ipod\ touch)\b/i
         :ipod 
       end

  os # => :win, :mac, :ipod, :ipod, :ipad

end
```

It's also possible to do something like this:

```
PLATFORMS = {
  mac:    /\b(?:mac|macintosh)\b/i,
  win:    /\b(?:win|windows)\b/i,
  ipad:   /\b(?:ipad)\b/i,
  iphone: /\b(?:iphone)\b/i,
  ipod:   /\b(?:ipod|ipod\ touch)\b/i
}

strings.each do |str|

  key = nil

  PLATFORMS.each_pair do |k, v|
    if str =~ v
      key = k
      break
    end
  end 

  key # => :win, :mac, :ipod, :ipod, :ipad

end
```

Or best:

```
strings.each do |str|

  PLATFORMS.find { |k, v| str =~ v }.first # => :win, :mac, :ipod, :ipod, :ipad

end
```

If you go with a hash and regular expressions, be more concise with your patterns. `\b` is a word boundary, and is how we tell the Regexp engine whether to match on substrings or whole words:

```
'machine'[/(?:mac|macintosh)/i]     # => "mac"
```

vs:

```
'machine'[/\b(?:mac|macintosh)\b/i] # => nil
```

Here's a bit more:

```
'mac'[/\b(?:mac|macintosh)\b/i]           # => "mac"
'macintosh'[/\b(?:mac|macintosh)\b/i]     # => "macintosh"
'win'[/\b(?:win|windows)\b/i]             # => "win"
'windows'[/\b(?:win|windows)\b/i]         # => "windows"
'ipad'[/\b(?:ipad)\b/i]                   # => "ipad"
'iphone'[/\b(?:iphone)\b/i]               # => "iphone"
'ipod touch'[/\b(?:ipod|ipod\ touch)\b/i] # => "ipod"
```

I'd probably do something like this to define the hash:

```
require 'regexp_trie'

PLATFORMS = {
  mac:    ['mac', 'macintosh'],
  win:    ['win', 'windows'],
  ipad:   ['ipad'],
  iphone: ['iphone'],
  ipod:   ['ipod', 'ipod touch']
}
```

Then, I'd transform the patterns to something more efficient:

```
PLATFORMS_RE = {}
PLATFORMS.each_pair do |k, v|
  PLATFORMS_RE[k] = /\b(?:#{RegexpTrie.union(v).source})\b/i
end
```

which results in:

```
PLATFORMS_RE
# => {:mac=>/\b(?:mac(?:intosh)?)\b/i,
#     :win=>/\b(?:win(?:dows)?)\b/i,
#     :ipad=>/\b(?:ipad)\b/i,
#     :iphone=>/\b(?:iphone)\b/i,
#     :ipod=>/\b(?:ipod(?:\ touch)?)\b/i}
```

Which then works as before:

```
strings.each do |str|

  PLATFORMS_RE.find { |k, v| str =~ v }.first # => :win, :mac, :ipod, :ipod, :ipad

end
```

Comment: A small thing: for 'ipod touch' to be matched `ipod` will be matched, so the former can be removed. btw, why did you escape the space there?

Comment: True about the iPod matches. Why escape the space? Because I was concentrating on the other stuff and didn't catch that. It's interesting that RegexpTrie also escapes it though.

Comment: I guess one reason is that it allows you to convert the regex to free-spoken mode (`/x`) without upsetting the apple cart.

Comment: Possibly. It doesn't hurt to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Not a big improvement, but you could detect just keys instead of key-value pairs

```
platform_to_regex = BrowserExperience::ExperienceKeeper::PLATFORMS
current_platform = platform_to_regex.keys.detect do |platform|        
   platform_to_regex[platform].match(user_agent_obj.platform)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `select` and to check using `match` which (or which ones) key value match with the string being passed:

```
PLATFORMS = {
  mac: /(mac)|(macintosh)/i,
  win: /(win)|(windows)/i,
  ipad: /(ipad)/i,
  iphone: /(iphone)/i,
  ipod: /(ipod)|(ipod touch)/i
}

def match_regex(string)
  PLATFORMS.select{|_,v| string.match(v)}.keys[0]
end

p match_regex('windows')
# => :win
```

Comment: My assumption for this string is that it can only match 1 regex expression.

Comment: So my question is superfluous.